# Reverse a string with ruby with recursion. What's wrong with this?

Tags: ruby

As said, I'd like to reverse a string in Ruby using recursion (I know how to do it with loops, but I can't wrap my mind around the recursion stuff yet). Here's what I got:

```
def reverseRecursive(s)

   if s.length==1 then 
      return s 
   else 
      return ((s[s.length-1,1] = s[(s.length-(s.length+1)),1]) + reverseRecursive(s.length-1))
  end
end

puts(reverseRecursive("hello"))
```

What's wrong with this? I replace the first letter with the last, then add the function with one letter less, the first letter is replaced with the last one again until there's only one letter left which ruby is supposed to put out.
Instead I get the following cryptic message:
undefined method 'length'for 4: Fixnum(NoMethodError)
So it recognized that I want the length of the string -1. How is this undefined? Length works always...

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Now that your question has been answered, let's have some fun by thinking up other ways to reverse a string using recursion.  Here's one:

```
def esrever(s)
  s.size < 2 ? s : s[-1] + esrever(s[1..-2]) + s[0]
end 

esrever("") # => "" 
esrever("a") # => "a" 
esrever("at") # => "ta" 
esrever("this seems to be working") # => "gnikrow eb ot smees siht"
```

- `esrever(s[1..-2])` passes all but the first and last characters of the string to itself.
- `s[-1] + esrever(s[1..-2]) + s[0]` reverses the first and last characters and sandwiches the reversed midsection between them.
- If the method receives a string of length zero or 1, there is nothing to do but return the string.
- You might want to look at "[Ruby Names](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html)" for a description of Ruby's naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
return ((s[s.length-1,1] = s[(s.length-(s.length+1)),1]) + reverseRecursive(s.length-1))
```

You are calling the `reverseRecursive` method with an integer:

```
 reverseRecursive(s.length-1)
```

and inside the method, you are trying to access the length of an integer which will give you an error:

I don't know about Ruby but the logic should be this:

```
return s[s.length-1] + reverseRecursive(s[0, s.length-1])
```

Comment: Hmm ok how do I fix it? This on its own

return ((s[s.length-1,1] = s[(s.length-(s.length+1)),1]))

gives me the last letter. When I add the +reverseRecursive(s.length-1)
for the recursion, it gives me the error... I tried giving it "to_s" on some parts, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an attempt to fix the recursion logic, instead it's to help you write better Ruby code:

```
def reverse_recursive(s)

  if s.length > 1 then 
    ((s[s.length - 1, 1] = s[(s.length - (s.length + 1)), 1]) + reverse_recursive(s.length - 1))
  else 
    s 
  end

end

puts(reverse_recursive("hello"))
```

- Methods in Ruby are written in snake_case, not camelCase, so use `reverse_recursive`.
- Use whitespace around operators like `+`, `=` and `=`. It's a readability thing for those other people who have no clue what you're doing, like your future self that can't remember why you wrote something a certain way, or a future employer who expects you to write in an idiomatic Ruby style.
- `if s.length==1 then` shouldn't have a trailing `then`. Use `then` for single line `if` tests:

  ```
  if s.length == 1 then return s
  ```

  But that isn't used in Ruby very often. Instead we'd use a trailing `if`:

  ```
  return s if s.length == 1
  ```
- Ruby allows, and it's idiomatic to use, implied return values. In other words, you don't have to use `return` at the end of a block or method to return the value. The last value seen will be what's returned by the method.
- The logic for your conditional test:

  ```
  if s.length==1 then 
    return s 
  else 
    return ((s[s.length-1,1] = s[(s.length-(s.length+1)),1]) + reverseRecursive(s.length-1))
  end
  ```

  has a problem if `s == ''`, because then you have a string length of 0, which isn't caught correctly:

  ```
  s = ''
  if s.length == 1
    s
  else 
    ((s[s.length - 1, 1] = s[(s.length - (s.length + 1)), 1]) + reverseRecursive(s.length - 1))
  end

  # ~> TypeError
  # ~> no implicit conversion of nil into String
  ```

  Use a better test and look for a string length > 1 like in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement needs to be altered a bit:

```
return s[s.length-1].chr + reverseRecursive(s[0, s.length-1])
```

You notice the `chr`? That is so you get the character at the position, and not the fixnum.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others the error is coming because you are passing an integer 's.length-1' into the recursive function, so when it checks it's length at line 3 it has an error because integers do not have a .length function.
Furthermore the logic and the syntax in the recursion is faulty. 
The logic should be s[last letter] + recursion(s[second..second last]) + s[first letter]. You need to switch the first with the last letter not replace the first with last, & then call the recursive function on the middle letters to keep swapping the first and last.
Syntactically, I'm not sure exactly how you were trying to achieve your goals because that is not written in ruby, here is more like how it should look:  
 
`def reverse_recursive(str)
    return str if str.length < 2 # not ==1 in case empty string passed in
    str[-1] + reverse_recursive("#{str[1..-2]}") + str[0] 
end`

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this would be the simplest way to use recursion.  It helps to identify the base case first.  In this case, the base case would be a single letter.  Assuming that works, then build from there.

```
def reverseRecursive(s)
    #returns the string if it is only a single letter
    return s if s.length <= 1

    #takes the last letter and assigns it to last
    last = s[-1]

    #assigns the rest of the string to rest
    rest = s[0...-1]

    #runs the rest of the string through the same method
    rest = reverseRecursive(rest)

    #adds them together
    return last + rest
end
```